# How do I go about figuring out delta-epsilon proofs?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, epsilon-delta

I'm going through Bert Mendelson's Introduction to Topology on my own. In fact, I've tried to go through it several times and I always get stuck somewhere. This time it's on limits. I think I understand the concept of the delta-epsilon proof. I want to show that that there is a certain range and distance such that whenever a comes within a certain range of b, f(a) comes within a certain distance of f(b). I think I finally understand that. But then I get to the exercises and I am just totally at a loss. I think I spent an hour on the first one today. If you could walk me through the thought process for this kind of proof that would be awesome, because I have no idea how to even start. Here's the first problem.

> Let $X$ be the set of continuous functions $f:[a,b]\to R$. Let $d$* be the distance function on $X$ defined by $$d^*(f,g)=\int_a^b|f(t)-g(t)|dt,$$ for $f,g\in X.$ For each $f\in X$, set $$I(f) = \int_a^bf(t)dt.$$
>   Prove that the function $I:(X,d^*)\to (R,d)$  is continuous.

In this case, d is just the absolute value of the difference between the two numbers.

Comment: For this one, you will need the *integral triangle inequality*, which is $|\int_a^b f(t) dt| \leq \int_a^b |f(t)| dt$. This will let you write $|I(f)-I(g)| \leq I(|f-g|)=d^*(f,g)$.

Comment: For "all practical purposes" integrals are just sums of step-functions over sufficiently fine partitions. For these functions, the "integral triangle inequality" becomes the "usual" triangle inequality (with a large number of summands). So it's sometimes helpful to see "what pops out at you" by assuming first the functions being "measured" are actually step-functions. The easiest class of such functions are, of course, constant functions, which reduces to a "normal" epsilon-delta proof. This isn't rigorous, but may help guide your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $f\in X$, given $\varepsilon >0$ we need to find $\delta >0$ such that:

(1) $g\in X$ and  $d^*(f,g)<\delta$ imply $|I(f)-I(g)|<\varepsilon$

Observe that, if $g\in X$:

$\left |I(f)-I(g)\right |=\left | \int_{a}^{b} f(t) -g(t) dt \right | ≤\int_{a}^{b} \left |f(t) -g(t) \right | dt=d^*(f,g)$

Hence if we take $\delta = \varepsilon$ we obtain:

$\left |I(f)-I(g)\right |≤d^*(f,g)<\delta=\varepsilon$

This means that $I$ is continuous at $f$, since condition (1)  is met.

Since $f \in X$ was arbirtrary, $I$ is continuous in $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the quantity that you wrote needs to be less epsilon is d*(f,g).

Comment: Oops. nevermind!

Comment: When doing these kind of problems, it is frequent to try to derive some useful inequality first (in this particular case it would be $\left |I(f)-I(g) \right |≤ d^*(f,g)$, which then points towards what $\delta$ is adequeate for each $\varepsilon$. It may be difficult to realize at first sight which $\delta$ will work.